# Setting TextView on top of ImageView - Android Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building an android app and I am trying to set my layout without any success.
I searched everywhere and I can't seem to find any solution.

I need to place 2 text views on top of an image.
the first text view need to be about 10dp above the vertical center of the image.
and the second text view should be below text view 1.

here's my code so far, though it doesn't work.
can anyone here tell me what I'm missing or what am I doing wrong?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.boromedia.parve.MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/blueOvalLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75sp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/blueOval"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/blueoval" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/greenOval"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/greenoval_small"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greenOvalText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/counter_activity_oval_done"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blueOvalText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/counter_activity_oval_text1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blueOvalTimer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/blueOvalText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/counter_default"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/head_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:text="@string/main_title"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/counter_activity_stop_button"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

[image: a picture of how it is now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this workaround: Change your textView for:

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blueOvalText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/counter_activity_oval_text1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is a wrapper for setting the margin of 10dp.
Don't forget that your second textview should be below the wrapper, not below the textview!

I hope this would help;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply.
I just tried that, but it's in the center, i need 10 dp above the center.. how do I do that exactly?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Put a wrapper around the TextView, that will set the margin. Try with this... good luck man. @Pro5per

Comment: If it does not work, change         android:layout_centerInParent="true" for     android:layout_centerVertical="true".. just in case it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your 2 TextView in a LinearLayout which will be centered in the parent :

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/blueOvalText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/counter_activity_oval_text1"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/blueOvalTimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/blueOvalText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/counter_default"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: done that already, but i need the text to be 10dp above the center, and idea how to achieve that?